# Error "function 'nop'" when building android kernel

Tags: android, linux, kernel, android-kernel

I am making the android kernel for the first time and after few errors(which I have overcome) I am getting below error log:

```
casual@Casual-PC:/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel$ 
make O=../out -j4
  GEN     /media/casual/USB/out/Makefile
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  Using /media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel as source     for kernel
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[2]: «include/generated/mach-types.h» не требует обновления. (dont     need update)
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    /media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-    DKernel/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC      arch/arm/common/vic.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.o
  CC      init/main.o
  CC      arch/arm/common/timer-sp.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.o
  LD      arch/arm/common/built-in.o
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/process.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/init.o
  LD      arch/arm/net/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/ptrace.o
  CC      init/do_mounts.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_rd.o
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/arch/arm/mm/init.c: In function 'mem_init':
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/arch/arm/mm/init.c:921:6: warning: format '%d' expects argument of         
type 'int', but argument 7 has type 'long int' [-Wformat]
error, forbidden warning: init.c:921
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'arch/arm/mm/init.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/mm/init.o] Error 1
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/Makefile:957: recipe for target 'arch/arm/mm' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mm] Error 2
make[1]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/sched_clock.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_initrd.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_md.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/signal.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/armksyms.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/bios32.o
  LD      init/mounts.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/isa.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/sleep.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/machine_kexec.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/io.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/crash_dump.o
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/arch/arm/kernel/io.c: In function '_memcpy_fromio':
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/arch/arm/kernel/io.c:14:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'nop' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel/io.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/kernel/io.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/Makefile:957: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/kernel] Error 2
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

(sry for bad code blocks)
So, I have found similar questions, but I didn't understand the answer:
[android kernel build (first time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952868/android-kernel-build-first-time)

when i make it throw

```
`LC_ALL=C make O=../out`
```

it gives me(spoiler - LC_ALL=C don't work how i thought, so i translated it(as #) by myself):

```
casual@Casual-PC:/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel$ LC_ALL=C make O=../out
  Using /media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel as source for kernel
  GEN     /media/casual/USB/out/Makefile
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[2]: «include/generated/mach-types.h» не требует обновления. #dont need updates
  CALL    /media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/io.o
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/arch/arm/kernel/io.c: In function '_memcpy_fromio':
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/arch/arm/kernel/io.c:14:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'nop' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel/io.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/kernel/io.o] Error 1
/media/casual/USB/android_kernel_yotaphone2-DKernel/Makefile:957: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/kernel] Error 2
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow we prefer **editing** the question instead of *deleting* it and asking a new one about the same problem. I am about [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074745/make-error-when-building-android-kernel) you asked 2 days before and deleted it. No worries for the first time, but take it into account for the future questions.

Comment: okey... sorry...